# Проблема с вёрсткой, текст "кучкуется" при выезде анимации за пределы экрана

Tags: html, css3, анимация, вёрстка

```css
#info-block {
 position: absolute;
 top: 35vh;
 left: 0;
 transition: left 5s cubic-bezier(0, .5, .5, 0);
 padding: 20px 100px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 font-size: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="info-block" onclick="this.style.left='100vw'">Sample text, lorem ipsum !</
```

При нажатии на надпись, блок уезжает за пределы экрана, но проблема заключается в том, что текст искажается и пытается втиснуться в видимую область экрана. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#info-block {
 position: absolute;
 top: 35vh;
 left: 0;
 transition: left 5s cubic-bezier(0, .5, .5, 0);
 padding: 20px 100px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 font-size: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
        white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="info-block" onclick="this.style.left='100vw'">Sample text, lorem ipsum !</
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было обернуть текст в

и задать ему white-space: nowrap;

Comment: не могли бы вы выложить полностью полученный код, это могло бы помочь людям, столкнувшимся с той же проблемой.